# JavaScript Clock - Memory Leak issue using SetInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, memory-leaks

**Context**
I'm currently making a website, and want to try and produce a clock on the page which simply displays the time. To do this, I have created a **Timer** component in react which is posted below. I've found that when leaving my webpage open for an extended period and returning to it, the page is dead with the following memory error: `sbox_fatal_memory_exceeded`.  I've looked this up and couldn't find any relevant information, however from the error itself it's clear this has to do with exceeding memory constraints.

As such, I've spent several hours monitoring the page and using Chrome Dev tools to try and get a pin on where this is coming from. I've figured this can only really be coming from some pure JavaScript I've written, as the rest of the pages are simple React with CSS transitions, nothing particularly elaborate. My main suspect is this Timer component. I don't know how to recreate the memory leak or how to trigger it at all, it seems to just happen eventually at some undeclared point. It is worth noting this component is displayed over all pages, so if this were the source I'd expect it to be gradual and constant.

However, it seems that the website initially stays constant with heap allocation, only very slowly creeping for the first 10 minutes or so and then starts to get more noticeable chunks of heap allocated between snapshots until it starts to snowball at a higher pace.[Initial snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOaLz.jpg) [Second snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uxU4.jpg) [A look into the heap allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz3X8.jpg)

From looking into the Window heap allocation, I see thousands of the same entry for a DOM Timer, all of which are related to the Timer.js Component

---

**Code**
With the code attached below, I'd like to know:

- Is there an underlying fault with the construction of the Timer class, causing this memory leak, or am I mistaken in thinking this is the source of the problem?
- If so, what part of the code is causing this, such that I can better understand this and avoid it in future.

If I were to guess, I suspect the fact I'm not clearing the interval may be an issue, though I don't want to as I want this to be consistently updating the time every minute. Or perhaps every time the component re-renders, it causes teh `CallMe()` method to be called again, causing an exponentially growing number of calls being made the longer the page is running? If indeed this Timer is the issue, how should I go about restructuring my code such that I can avoid this issue?

```
    class Timer extends React.Component{
        state = {
            date: new Date(),
            days: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        };

       callMe(){
            setInterval(() => {
                this.setState({date: new Date()});
            }, 60000);
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <span className="local-time local-text nav-anim-in">Local Time:&nbsp;</span>
                    <span className="local-time local-day nav-anim-in">{this.state.days[this.state.date.getUTCDay()]}&nbsp;</span>
                    <span className="local-time local-hour nav-anim-in"> {this.state.date.getUTCHours()}</span>
                    <span className="local-time clock-colon">:</span>
                    <span className="local-time local-minute nav-anim-in">{this.state.date.getUTCMinutes().length === 1 ? '0'+this.state.date.getUTCMinutes() : this.state.date.getUTCMinutes() }</span>
                    {this.callMe()}
                </div>

            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Likely re-rendering is adding more and more setIntervals to the window.  Put a console.log inside callMe and see if it gets executed more than once.

Comment: the interval should be initialised in `componentDidMount()` and cleared in `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4286486-build-web-apps-with-reactjs/4286711-build-a-ticking-clock-component#/id/r-4295067

Comment: Ah I see, I'll give that a try and see if that fixes it. Out of curiosity, is this significant enough to be causing such a large memory leak, or does it seem like perhaps there's more to that could be causing this? I'm aware that for every function call JavaScript creates and places a stackframe on the heap, though I'm unsure about how intensive this is memory wise. In short, I'm trying to gauge if this could feasibly be the sole source of this issue, or infact I may have other problems at hand.

Comment: Also if either of you'd like to respond with this as an answer I can select it as a solution

Comment: Having a large number of setIntervals will definitely eat up memory and could be the sole problem.

Comment: @Andrew So there's a single instance of Timer on the page currently, as for how long it takes, I'd say somewhere in the range of 20-30 minutes before heap allocation starts to snowball

Comment: Just to confirm, I've implemented the fix and the heap hasn't budged over the past 10 minutes of testing, so I think this was the sole source of the leak. Thanks so much guys, I've been trying to find this among my web app for the past day so it's really great to finally have this fixed! Guess that teaches me for blindly copying code off a SO answer I found earlier on for how to make a clock..